# How to monitor kafka-offset lag without consuming it

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

I am working for a retail giant as Kafka resource, they want to monitor the lags without having consumer.
I found some tools like Burrow, but that looks like linux specific while i have to test that in windows and then apply.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you cannot run a Linux VM or container?

Burrow is written in Golang, so it can be compiled to run in Windows. And Burrow *does* consume the consumer group topic and compute statistics on it...

There are also other tools out there like ones written by Lightbend, Zalando, Confluent, and likely others such as a Prometheus Lag exporter project on Github because lag is an important metric to track in any industry...

Consuming group information doesn't alter anything